# JQGrid Add New Record

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, jqgrid

I have a JQGrid that holds notes on a Contact Edit Form that are associated with that contact. I'm trying to get the `Add New Note` feature working but I can't get the `ContactId` passed to the controller. the `ContactId` is present with the `Edit` and `Delete` and they seem to be working just fine. The `Note` is passed to the controller for the `Add New` but not the `ContactId`

View JQuery

```
  $("#JQGrid1").jqGrid({
    url: '@Url.Action("GetNotes", "Contact")',
    editurl: '@Url.Action("EditNote", "Contact")',
    mtype: "GET",
    datatype: "json",
    page: 1,
    postData: { id: document.getElementById('SelectedContact_ContactID').value },
    jsonReader: { id: document.getElementById('SelectedContact_ContactID').value },
    prmNames: { id: document.getElementById('SelectedContact_ContactID').value },
    colNames: ["Id", "ContactId", "Note", "Date Created", "Created By"],
    colModel: [
        { editable: true, key: true, width: 50, name: "ID", hidden: true },
        { editable: true, width: 60, name: "ContactId", hidden: true },
        { editable: true, width: 460, name: "Note", hidden: false },
        {
            editable: false,
            width: 160,
            name: "DateCreated",
            formatter: "date",
            formatoptions: { srcformat: "m/d/Y h:i:s A", newformat: "y-m-d" },
            hidden: false
        },
        { editable: false, width: 160, name: "CreatedBy", hidden: false },
    ],
    height: "auto",
    caption: "Notes",
    rowNum: 5,
    pager: "#JQGrid1_pager",
    loadComplete: function() {
        //alert("OK");
    },
    loadError: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert('HTTP status code: ' + jqXHR.status + "\n" +
            'textStatus: ' + textStatus + "\n" +
            'errorThrown: ' + errorThrown);
        alert('HTTP message body (jqXHR.responseText): ' + "\n" + jqXHR.responseText);
    },
}).jqGrid('navGrid', '#JQGrid1_pager', { edit: true, add: true, del: true, search: false, view: false, refresh: true },
{
    // edit options
    closeAfterEdit: true,
},
{
    //add options
    closeAfterAdd: true,
},
{
    // del options

});
```

Controller Code

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EditNote(string oper, int? ID, int ContactId, string Note)
    {
        switch (oper)
        {
            case "add":
            {
                ContactNote cn = new ContactNote
                {
                    ContactId = (int)ContactId,
                    Note = Note,
                    DateCreated = DateTime.Now,
                    CreatedBy = User.Identity.Name
                };
                _contactNoteRepository.Upsert(cn);
                return Content("true");
            }
            case "del":
                _contactNoteRepository.Delete((int)ID);
                return Content("true");
            case "edit":
            {
                ContactNote cn = new ContactNote
                {
                    ID = (int)ID,
                    ContactId = (int)ContactId,
                    Note = Note,
                    DateCreated = DateTime.Now,
                    CreatedBy = User.Identity.Name
                };
                _contactNoteRepository.Upsert(cn);
                return Content("true");
            }
        }

        return Content("false");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution

```
editoptions: {defaultValue:'aValue'}
```

So I edited the line

```
{ editable: true, width: 60, name: "ContactId", hidden: true },
```

to

```
{ editable: true, width: 60, name: "ContactId", hidden: true, editoptions: {defaultValue:document.getElementById('SelectedContact_ContactID').value} },
```

and this populated the ContactId in the form and it was passed to the controller method.